# filling dynamic XFA form with dynamic content with itext 7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7, xfa

I would like to know if there is a way to access events on xfa forms with dynamic content, i have my xml generated, works when setting the values for some nodes but for those nodes where the value is on dependency with others and is setted with an js event doesnt work. There is some way to access that event? or is not possible with itext 7

Comment: Hi, please provide examples of what is working and what is not working and what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible access events from xml. But you can use XFA application events to set/change UI after data is rendered. In my case I use docReady to change the UI.